# Why is the dualizing sheaf $\omega_X$ locally free of rank 1 at generic points for a scheme $X$ satisfying $G_0$ and $S_2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, duality-theorems, coherent-sheaves

In his paper [Generalized Divisors and Biliaison](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1258735326) *Hartshorne* states that if $X$ is a noetherian, embeddable (say projective) scheme of pure dimension which satisfies the conditions $S_2$ (Serre conditions) and $G_0$ (all of $X$'s local rings of dimension zero are Gorenstein rings), then the dualizing sheaf $\omega_X$ of $X$ is locally free of rank one at the generic points of $X$. The statement can be found in Definition-Remark 2.7 here [Generalized Divisors and Biliaison from Hartshorne](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1258735326).

> Whats the reason for that? And what can we say about the support of $\omega_X$ in terms of the generic points?

**Some thoughts on this:**

For the sake of simplicity assume that $X$ is of dimension one and defined over the field $k$ and thus finite over ${\mathbb{P}_k^1}$ with $f:X \to {\mathbb{P}_k^1}$. Then by 6.4.26 (b) from Qing Liu's book we have $\omega_X \cong \omega_f \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} f^*\omega_g$ where $g:{\mathbb{P}_k^1} \to \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ is the structure morphism and $\omega_g$ the one-dualizing sheaf of $g$ and $\omega_f$ the 0-dualizing sheaf of $f$. Since $\omega_g$ is invertible, the same is true for its pullback $f^*\omega_g$ and hence it is enough to prove that  $\omega_f$ is locally free at the generic points of $X$. By 6.4.25 we have  $$\omega_f \cong \mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$$
considered as an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module via the multiplication into the argument. Therefor it would be enough to prove that $\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$ is locally free of rank one at every generic point of $X$. But I do not see why this is true only because $X$ is $S_1$ (which is enough here) and $G_0$.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Since $X$ is of pure dimension, the stalk of $\omega_X$ at every generic point $\eta$ of $X$ is a dualizing module for $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$. But $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ is Gorenstein by assumption, and hence $\omega_{X,\eta}$ is a free $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$-module of rank one.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Thank your for your answer! Could you please give me a reference for your first statement?

Comment: You can deduce it from the references in \[Stacks, [Tag 0AWK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AWK)\], but here is a sketch: the dualizing complex $\omega_X^\bullet$ localizes to a dualizing complex at every point, and using the fact that $X$ is of pure dimension, taking cohomology tells you that the sheaf $\omega_X$ localizes to a dualizing module for $\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$. I can rewrite the details if you need me to, but it's hard to write down succinctly.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Thank you for your reply. It would be gerat if you could tell me the place in the Stacks-Project where I find that the "dualizing sheaf" defined there really defines the duality condition as in Liu 6.4.18 or Hartshorne AlgGeo III 7.6.! My problem is that I really do not know anything about the langauge of complexes etc. and thus it would be great to see that the definition of $\omega_X$ in stacks really does what it should do (duality).

Comment: The Stacks project defines $\omega_X$ in [Tag 0AWH](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AWH), and [Tag 0AWP](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AWP) proves that the sheaf is dualizing in the sense of Hartshorne or Liu. Personally, I (following [Sándor Kovács](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48145/dualizing-sheaf/48200#comment116720_48146), for instance) prefer $\omega_X$ to be called a *canonical* module, though, since it is not dualizing in the sense of Serre or Grothendieck duality.

Comment: Thank you again for your polite answer! I guess I need you to write an answer in which (as you offered to) you deduce that the canonical module $\omega_X$ localizes to the canonical module of the local ring of any generic point of $X$. I would really appreciate it if you could do that. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109471/discussion-between-windsheaf-and-takumi-murayama).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, I am fleshing out the details from my comments. I have decided just to stick to the terminology and the conventions in the Stacks project. We start with some definitions in the local case.

**Definition 1** [Stacks, [Tag 0A7B](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A7B)]**.** Let $A$ be a noetherian ring. A *dualizing complex* $\omega_A^\bullet$ is a complex of $A$-modules such that

1. $\omega_A^\bullet$ has finite injective dimension;
2. $\mathbf{h}^i(\omega_A^\bullet)$ is a finite $A$-module for all $i$; and
3. $A \to \operatorname{\mathbf{R}Hom}_A(\omega_A^\bullet,\omega_A^\bullet)$ is a quasi-isomorphism.

**Definition 2** [Stacks, [Tag 0A7M](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A7M)]**.** Let $(A,\mathfrak{m},k)$ be a noetherian local ring with a dualizing complex $\omega_A^\bullet$. We say that $\omega_A^\bullet$ is *normalized* if $\operatorname{\mathbf{R}Hom}_A(k,\omega_A^\bullet) = k[0]$.

By [Stacks, [Tag 0A7F](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A7F) and [Tag 0A7L](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A7L)], normalized dualizing complexes are unique up to isomorphism, and every dualizing complex is isomorphic to a shift of a normalized dualizing complex.

**Definition 3** [Stacks, [Tag 0DW3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DW3)]**.** Let $(A,\mathfrak{m},k)$ be a noetherian local ring of dimension $d$ with a normalized dualizing complex $\omega_A^\bullet$. The module
$$\omega_A := \mathbf{h}^{-d}(\omega_A^\bullet)$$
is called a *dualizing module*.

Dualizing modules are closely related to the following notion:

**Definition 4** [[Waldi](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0059382), Definition 5.6]**.** Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be a noetherian local ring of dimension $d$. A finitely generated $A$-module $K$ is a *canonical module* for $A$ if
$$\operatorname{Hom}_A\bigl(K,E_A(A/\mathfrak{m})\bigr) \simeq H^d_{\mathfrak{m}}(A).$$

A canonical module, if it exists, is finitely generated and unique up to isomorphism [[Waldi](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0059382), Satz 5.16 and Bemerkung 5.7]. Canonical modules are also known as *modules of dualizing differentials* or *dualizing modules*; see [[Aoyama](https://doi.org/10.1215/kjm/1250521612), p. 85]. Dualizing modules in the sense of Definition 3 are indeed examples of canonical modules [Stacks, [Tag 0DW3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DW3)].

We now consider the global case.

**Definition 5** [Stacks, [Tag 0A87](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A87)]**.** Let $X$ be a locally noetherian scheme. An object $\omega_X^\bullet$ of $D(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is called a *dualizing complex* if, for every affine open subset $U = \operatorname{Spec}(A) \subseteq X$, there exists a dualizing complex $\omega_A^\bullet$ for $A$ such that $\omega_X^\bullet\rvert_U$ is isomorphic to the image of $\omega_A^\bullet$ under $\widetilde{(\,\cdot\,)}\colon D(A) \to D(\mathcal{O}_U)$.

**Definition 6** [Stacks, [Tag 0AWH](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AWH)]**.** Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme with a dualizing complex $\omega_X^\bullet$. Let $n \in \mathbf{Z}$ be the smallest integer such that $\mathbf{h}^n(\omega_X^\bullet)$ is nonzero. The coherent sheaf
$$\omega_X := \mathbf{h}^n(\omega_X^\bullet)$$
is called a *dualizing sheaf*. Note that $\omega_X$ depends on the choice of $\omega_X^\bullet$.

When $X$ is proper over a field, then the sheaf $\omega_X$ satisfies the definition of a dualizing sheaf in [[Hartshorne](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3849-0), p. 241]; see [Stacks, [Tag 0AWP](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AWP)]. On the other hand, under the same assumptions on $X$, $\omega_X$ does not satisfy Serre duality unless $X$ is Cohen–Macaulay and equidimensional by [[Hartshorne](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3849-0), Theorem III.7.6].

Since a dualizing sheaf is not the same thing as a dualizing complex that happens to be a sheaf (in the sense that it is concentrated in one degree), the sheaf $\omega_X$ is also called a *canonical sheaf*. This terminology comes from the fact that if $X$ is a geometrically normal variety of dimension $d$, then
$$\omega_X \simeq \mathcal{O}_X(K_X) \simeq j_*\Bigl(\bigwedge^d\Omega_{X_\mathrm{sm}}\bigr),$$
where $K_X$ is a canonical divisor on $X$, and where $X_\mathrm{sm}$ is the smooth locus of $X$ and $j\colon X_\mathrm{sm} \hookrightarrow X$ is the natural open embedding.

Another reason for the terminology *canonical sheaf* comes from the fact that the sheaf $\omega_X$ is the global version of a canonical module of a noetherian local ring, which was your original question.

**Proposition 7.** *Let $X$ be a connected noetherian scheme of finite Krull dimension $d$ with a dualizing complex $\omega_X^\bullet$. For every point $x \in X$ in the support of the canonical sheaf $\omega_X$ associated to $\omega_X^\bullet$, the module $\omega_{X,x}$ is a canonical module for $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. In particular, if $X$ is equidimensional, then $\omega_{X,x}$ is a canonical module for $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for every $x \in X$.*

*Proof.* Let $n$ be the integer such that $\omega_X = \mathbf{h}^n(\omega_X^\bullet)$. After shifting $\omega_X^\bullet$, we may assume that $n = -d$. Then, for every point $x \in X$ such that $\dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) = d$, we see that $\omega_{X,x}^\bullet$ is a normalized dualizing complex for $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ by [Stacks, [Tag 0A7Z](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A7Z)].

We now note that the support of $\omega_X$ is the union of irreducible components of $X$ of dimension $d$ by [Stacks, [Tag 0AWK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AWK)]. Thus, we have $\omega_{X,x} = \mathbf{h}^{-d}\omega_{X,x}^\bullet$ for every point $x \in X$ such that $\dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) = d$, and hence $\omega_{X,x}$ is a dualizing module for $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, and is also a canonical module for $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ by [Stacks, [Tag 0DW3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DW3)]. Moreover, every point $y \in X$ contained in the support of $\omega_X$ specializes to a point $x \in X$ such that $\dim(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) = d$, and $\omega_{X,y}$ is therefore a canonical module for $\mathcal{O}_{X,y}$ by the fact that canonical modules on local rings localize to localizations at every prime ideal in their support [[Aoyama](https://doi.org/10.1215/kjm/1250521612), Corollary 4.3].

Finally, the "in particular" statement follows from the fact that if $X$ is equidimensional, then the support of $\omega_X$ is all of $X$ by [Stacks, [Tag 0AWK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AWK)]. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I will go through this in detail soon, but I would like to already thank you a lot for your work you've put in here to give such an extensive answer!!